# inserting a username to proftpd configuration file

Tags: shell, sed, scripting, proftpd

I need to insert a new `ftp user` in the configuration file of proftpd `proftpd.conf`
The username must be an argument passed by the user and it should automatically be entered in the proftpd.conf.This can be done by using a shell script(using sed command).Already I had a shell script to add a user.

```
#!/bin/bash
useradd $1
mkdir /home/$2
passwd $1
exit
```

This user must be added to `proftpd.conf`
guys help please.....

Comment: Regarding the `proftpd.conf` issue, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I dont have problems with proftpd.conf.I need a script that would automatically add ftp users to the proftpd.conf....help dude...

Comment: The code that you have posted so far is irrelevant to your question.  I was asking: what you have tried so far that is relevant?

Comment: I had made a script that would automatically install proftpd .Then I needed some ftp users to be added,so it must be specified in the proftpd.conf.The script should take username and home directory as argument. The script should test that the new user can indeed upload and download files using passive mode of operation.

Comment: Just put the users into a group, say, `ftpusers`, and put `AllowGroup ftpusers` into the `<Limit LOGIN>` part of the `proftpd` config. This is precisely the sort of thing for which groups exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/utils/ftpasswd.html
```

It helps to read the manual.  You don't need to do surgery on any files.  Something like this:

```
# cat users-to-add | xargs -n1 ftpasswd --passwd --name={} --home=/home/() --shell=/bin/false
```